# How to create a Recyclerview with circle buttons

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I create this view..?

I appreciate your help and can guide me to investigate or help with an example of how to create a `RecyclerView` like this.

[image]

Comment: You could create a RecyclerView with the `GridLayoutManager` and use rounded buttons as list items. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#modifying-layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess to do a `RecyclerView` like the one above, you need to create a custom layout which has rounded buttons (I'll provide you a library that might help you), and to organize them that, you might need to consider using `GridView` layout and you give it a span (like if you want to have 4 or 5 buttons in one horizonal line)

This is the library for rounded buttons

https://github.com/MuhammadArsalanChishti/Cuboid-Circle-Button

Answer (score 2):

You need `GridLayoutManager`. First, you need to make a `listItems` for your `RecyclerView`, for example make a list of the items you need because here you need a Circle Button I will model something similar

**item.xml** (RecycleView Layout)

```
....
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutRecycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvYourId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_circle" />
    </LinearLayout>
....
```

**item_circle.xml** (Design Layout listItem RecycleView)

```
....
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutYourId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BadgeCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/app_badge_count"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
....
```

**app_badge_count.xml** (to define a circle shape)

```
....
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#FF0000"/>

    <size
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"/>

</shape>
....
```

**Result :**

[image: Result]

And make your `RecycleView` Layout apply `GridLayoutManager`

```
YourIdRecycleView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(getContext(), "TheRowThatYouNeed", GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```

For more information about `GridLayoutManager` check [here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C5CHFA_enID880ID880&sxsrf=ALeKk01UYxSYq6d_imf8GKy90kon0ZFl7Q%3A1594773957688&ei=xVEOX__GKdSvyAOnzp2QCA&q=recycleview%20spancount%20android&oq=recycleview%20spancount%20android&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIKCAAQCBANEAoQHjIICAAQCBANEB46BwgjELACECc6CggAEA0QBRAeEBM6CggAEAgQDRAeEBM6BggAEA0QHjoICAAQDRAFEB46CAghEBYQHRAeOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEBYQChAeUK4NWIgXYIoYaABwAHgAgAH6AYgBoQqSAQUzLjYuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi_vfr5g87qAhXUF3IKHSdnB4IQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), I hope this helps you